# Faceting & result grouping in solr version 6.6

Tags: solr

In the solr query, parameter group.facet=true but I am even trying to apply interval faceting but after query is executed solr is giving the following error

"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
msg "Interval Faceting can't be used with group.facet"
code 400

solr version is 6.6

I came across one blog - https://blog.trifork.com/2012/04/10/faceting-result-grouping/

which says "In Solr grouped faceting builds further on the existing faceting parameters and can just be enabled by using the following parameter as is described on the Solr wiki:
group.facet=true
When enabled all the already specified field facets (facet.field parameters) will be computed as grouped facets. Both single and multivalued field facets are supported. **Other facet types like range facets aren’t supported yet.**"

But I am not sure about solr version. Is this supported in solr 6.6

I have the following data

doc = [{
"productID" : 100025,
"days" : 1,
"rating" : 5,
},
"productID" : 100025,
"days" : 3,
"rating" : 5,
},
"productID" : 100025,
"days" : 5,
"rating" : 5,
}
]

My query for the solr have these parameters

```
facet.interval = rating
group = true
group.field = productID

f.rating.facet.interval.set = {!key=5}[5,*]
```

response for facet is like this

```
 ~"facet_counts": {},
       "facet_intervals": {
         "rating": {
            "5": 3,
          }
        }~
```

however the expected result should like

```
  ~"facet_counts": {},
        "facet_intervals": {
          "rating": {
            "5": 1,
          }
        }~
```

also I tried with "group.facet = true" 
but I am getting the following error

```
"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
msg "Interval Faceting can't be used with group.facet"
code 400
```

Comment: Sounds like the error message is telling you that it isn't supported in 6.6? Have you tried using the collapse and expand support instead? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have updated the post